# How to fit objects in the canvas with the canvas sizeh in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, object, tkinter, canvas, resize

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.geometry('700x700')
canvas=Canvas(root,bg='white',height=600,width=600)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_line(0,0,100,0)
canvas.create_line(100,0,100,100)
canvas.create_line(100,100,0,100)
canvas.create_line(0,100,0,0)
mainloop()
```

here is an example problem. in this, i want to resize all the lines together and fit them with the canvas window. how this can be done? I want a general solution for any group of canvas objects like oval,polygon,arc...etc

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def resize_to_fill(canvas):
    global bbox, xfactor, yfactor, factor, x, y # For debug only
    # Get the [minx, miny, maxx, maxy] of all of the canvas items:
    bbox = [float("inf"), float("inf"), float("-inf"), float("-inf")]
    for id in canvas.find_all():
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.bbox(id)
        bbox[0] = min(bbox[0], x1)
        bbox[1] = min(bbox[1], y1)
        bbox[2] = max(bbox[2], x2)
        bbox[3] = max(bbox[3], y2)

    # This is needed to get the width and height of the canvas
    canvas.update()

    # Calculate the scale factors
    xfactor = canvas.winfo_width() / (bbox[2]-bbox[0])
    yfactor = canvas.winfo_height() / (bbox[3]-bbox[1])

    canvas.moveto("all", 0, 0)

    canvas.scale("all", 0, 0, xfactor, yfactor)


root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(False, False)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg="white", width=600, height=600,
                   highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()

# Change this to `False` if you want to test the second example
if True:
    canvas.create_line(0, 0, 100, 0, fill="red")
    canvas.create_line(100, 0, 100, 100, fill="blue")
    canvas.create_line(100, 100, 0, 100, fill="black")
    canvas.create_line(0, 100, 0, 0, fill="green")
else:
    canvas.create_line(50, 50, 100, 50, fill="red")
    canvas.create_line(100, 50, 100, 100, fill="blue")
    canvas.create_line(100, 100, 50, 100, fill="black")
    canvas.create_line(50, 100, 50, 50, fill="green")

button = tk.Button(root, text="Resize to fit canvas",
                   command=lambda: resize_to_fill(canvas))
button.pack(fill="x")

root.mainloop()
```

It's mostly maths but basically what I do is:

- Get the `min(x)`, `min(y)`, `max(x)` and `max(y)` of all of the objects
- Calculate the x and y factors
- Move all objects to `(0, 0)` to make the scaling easier
- Scale all object by `xfactor` and `yfactor` from `(0, 0)`

Notes:

- It doesn't keep the aspect ratio.
- Sometimes it leaves a gap between the edges of the screen. I have no idea why

Comment: Thanks,it works perfectly for given example.But in most of cases,when resizing,the objects in the canvas resize beyond the canvas size.Can you give a generalized resizing code for any given object in the canvas?

Comment: @abdullathahir I made it so it resizes the canvas to fit all of the objects inside the canvas. If I make it so it resizes to fit a single object, the rest of the objects wouldn't be visible. What did you put on the canvas, for it not to work? It might be that my code is buggy. Also it doesn't keep the aspect ratio, so it's possible for your objects to get swished into a line.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
x = 600
y = 600

tk = Tk()
canvas=Canvas(tk, bg='white', height=x, width=y)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_line(x + a certain number, y + a certain number, x + a certain number, y + a certain number)
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.